# How to collapse (hide or swipe up) Navigation Bar (Title Bar) while scrolling in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a `ContentPage` that has a Navigation Bar (Title Bar) above that contains Title of the page. I want the Navigation Bar to collapse whenever the content (possibly `ListView`) is scrolled up, and the Navigation Bar must appear again (swipe down) when content is scrolled down.

Please note that I am using `FlyoutPage` formerly known as `MasterDetailPage`.

**Here is my XAML code**

```xml
<ContentPage ...
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             Title="Home">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout...>
                            <Label... />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Similar to this:**

[image: Similar to this1]

**How can I achieve this in Xamarin.Forms?**

Answer (score 4):

### Steps:

1. Fake a title bar and set a reference name.
2. Attach scrolled event.
3. Add animation.

Check sample code or [sample project here](https://github.com/shawyunz/XampleControl/blob/main/XampleControl/XampleControl/09ScrollToHideNavigationBar.xaml).

### XAML page

```
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
            <StackLayout
                x:Name="TitleLayout"
                BackgroundColor="#2296f3"
                HeightRequest="58"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label
                    Margin="40,0,0,0"
                    FontSize="20"
                    Text="Title"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            </StackLayout>
            <ListView ...
                      Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled" >
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

### XAML.cs class

```
        private double previousOffset;

        private async void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            double translation;
            bool visibility;

            if (previousOffset < e.ScrollY - 45) //scroll sensitivity
            {
                translation = -58; //same Title bar height
                visibility = false;
            }
            else if (previousOffset > e.ScrollY + 45)
            {
                translation = 0;
                visibility = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

            await TitleLayout.TranslateTo(TitleLayout.TranslationX, translation, 300);
            await Task.Delay(100);
            TitleLayout.IsVisible = visibility;
            previousOffset = e.ScrollY;
        }
```